# should I use text or longtext for table column?

Tags: mysql, laravel

whats the difference? is text() enough?

I just found abuot this: $table->longText('description');

and made me wonder if text alone would be enough for content that can be of any lenght, lets say blog post, which one do you use?

Comment: "is text enough?" Clearly, it depends on the data you're planning to store. There are different options available so that you can choose what suits your use case. There's no "right" answer to this. if there was, there wouldn't be a choice available.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

each type manage different max length

> VARCHAR(M), VARBINARY(M)    255 
>   bytes, or  more than 255 bytes
>
> TINYBLOB, TINYTEXT  L L < 2^8
>
> BLOB, TEXT  L  < 2^16
>
> MEDIUMBLOB, MEDIUMTEXT  L  < 2^24
>
> LONGBLOB, LONGTEXT  L  < 2^32

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-type-overview.html

Comment: I understand the sizes now I did check, what would you preffer or use if you were creating CMS, what would you use in table for posts where you store body of a post, text or mediumtext?

Comment: depend (obviuosly ) by the max lenght  ..but typically i use text  taht contain a variablile value  eg form 1 to 16,777,215   bytes  (if you store plain text)

Comment: I will be storing plain text, I was wondering what if user inputs a small book worth of 50 pages of text, then standard text will not be enough. I am building CMS and I do not know in advance what enduser may want to put in a post or page body column

Comment: then you can  use mediumtext without problem ,. .. in my case the user post at max one or few page  ..(remeber tha average size of a page is 1800 char)

Answer (score 1):

If you look at [illuminate/database sources](https://github.com/illuminate/database/blob/master/Schema/Grammars/ChangeColumn.php#L159), which is used by Laravel, there is method to set max length for a text column.

```
protected static function calculateDoctrineTextLength($type)
{
    switch ($type) {
        case 'mediumText':
            return 65535 + 1;
        case 'longText':
            return 16777215 + 1;
        default:
            return 255 + 1;
    }
}
```

Default type is text, so `text` field will be 255 characters long, and `longtext` is 16777215.